# appending data to a form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, model-view-controller, submit

Hey so I'm trying to override a form submit to append dynamic data from an associative object

I have an html form that I want to override the on sumbit click with out using ajax

```
$('#form-3').submit(function () {
        var atc = 0;
        OutputData = {};
        $('#alttitlestable').find('tr').each(function () {
            if ($(this).data('value') != undefined {
                OutputData["alttitles" + atc] = $(this).data('value');
                atc++;
            }
        });

        OutputData['alttitlecount'] = atc;

        var ntc = 0;
        $('#alttitlestable').find('.addedtitle').each(function () {
            OutputData["newalttitlename"+ntc] = $(this).find('td input').val();
            OutputData["newalttitletype"+ntc] = $(this).find('td select').val();
            ntc++;
        });

        OutputData['newtitlecount'] = ntc;

        var input = $("<input>").attr({"type":"hidden","name":"outputdata"}).val(OutputData);
        $('#form-3').append(input);
    });
```

However, when I grab the data from the formcollection it returns form["outputdata"] it just returns a string [Object object].

Any Idea on how to fix this?
Also, its there a better way to serialize my table of values?

Comment: `I want to override the on sumbit click with out using ajax` ... what do you mean?

Comment: I want to over-ride clicking the submit button on the form. I don't want to create an ajax function to replace the form submit

Comment: I do understand what you do not want to do. Thanks. What would you like to do and how? When do you start, what's your trigger? What & how have you tried?

Comment: If I were to use ajax I would be able to say Data: OutputData to set the associative array as the data.

I want to Append the Associative array I created to the post data that is sent when I click the submit button from the form.  

So the form would send all of its named input elements over, plus the data that is contained by OutputData.  -Thanks

Comment: I thought there was no `submitting` the form? .. Did you consider converting your object into a json string? `JSON.stringify( object )` -- before putting it into a form element.

Comment: We can submit the form I just wanted to append the Associative array to the post data some how.  JSON.stringify the object will work but then I have to convert it back after I grab it out of the form data.

Comment: Unfortunately the only format to submit form data is `string`; you cannot submit an object or an array. But you can submit a file.